# How to compare dates which is stored as String(varchar) in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a database(table), in which 2 fields are:

```
fromdate varchar(20)
todate  varchar(20)
```

Dates are stored in this fashion:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
```

For ex: '2014-10-30 10:10:10' in database.

Now I want to compare two dates and fetch records from database by using query, 2014-09-10 10:10:10(`fromdate`) to 2014-10-10 10:10:10(`todate`)

How to fetch all accurate records.. Is there any kind of solution..

Thanks.

Comment: Why are `datetime`s stored as `varchar` at all?

Comment: its legacy database! all dates are stored in varchar..and we have to migrate the application without changing database structure..

Comment: You have to decide first - if your database MySql, SqlServer or Oracle. Why all of them in tags?

Comment: OTOH, the advantage of the way they are stored (yyyy downto ss) is that alphabetical ordering of these timestamps === chronological ordering, so you should be able to test the strings and get the same result you would, as with dates.

Comment: `DATE` is never stored in any format. It is for us, human beings to understand.

Oracle stores `DATE` in total of `7 bytes`. Each byte in it stores values for an element of the DATE. Read my answer.

Comment: actually we have all the databases!! with live data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compare the string without extra overhead.

This format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" shares chronological and <s>literal</s> alphabetical order

```
SELECT * FROM someTable
WHERE fromdate >= '2014-09-10 10:10:10' AND todate <= '2014-10-10 10:10:10'
```

Also, I would create an index on those columns.

Comment: @fvu +1, you said it better than I. I should said alphabetical instead of literal

Answer (score 2):

> i have a database(table), in which 2 fields are: fromdate varchar(20)
>   todate varchar(20)

It is a design flaw. Date should always be a `DATE` data type and never be string.

> dates are stored in this fashion YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

`DATE` is never stored in any format. it is for us, human beings to understand.

Oracle stores `DATE` in total of `7 bytes`. Each byte in it stores values for an element of the DATE as follows:

```
Byte    Description
----    -------------------------------------------------
1       Century value but before storing it add 100 to it
2       Year and 100 is added to it before storing
3       Month
4       Day of the month
5       Hours but add 1 before storing it
6       Minutes but add 1 before storing it
7       Seconds but add 1 before storing it
```

> for eg :"2014-10-30 10:10:10" in database.
>
> Now i want to compare two dates and fetch records from database by
>   using query, 2014-09-10 10:10:10(fromdate) to 2014-10-10
>   10:10:10(todate)

Just use `to_date('2014-10-30 10:10:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

**NOTE** This is for Oracle database. I see you have tagged SQL Server too. I don't understand why did you do that.

Comment: As I said, use `to_date`

Comment: but the way you think dates are stored in database is wrong. Hope you understand now as I explained the 7 byte information.

Answer (score 1):

Use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
select * from your_table
where str_to_date(fromdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= '2014-09-10 10:10:10'
and str_to_date(todate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') <= '2014-10-10 10:10:10'
```

Comment: is str_to_date is a database vendor specific?

Comment: how actually it distinguish two dates which is stored in varchar?

Comment: we have almost all database and i need a universal query..so that it can work on any database..

Comment: @vineeth.soman: Then you need a different solution for every DB engine. Or what you should actually really do - change the data type to datetime and all will be fine - you need no function call and it is much faster

Comment: actually we thought about that..but the database contains live data..and we have to incorporate the old data also...our bad

Comment: @vineeth.soman: So - you can change the data type without losing the data.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you can use `convert` function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2014-10-30 18:00:00', 120)
```

**Second**, if you can't change the existing columns and their type, it does not mean that you can't add additional column with correct date type that duplicates the meaning of "wrong" column. This would both save your legacy code and help you in new development, as all the operations with convertation in queries are very expensive in terms of performance.