# How many bytes takes DateTime format in oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, datetime

Umm, Hello, can someone tell me how many bytes takes Date Time format in Oracle SQL pls ?

I tryed to find it with google, but i couldnt find it.
Thank for answer.

Comment: I just Googled ["date time oracle storage bytes"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enGB616GB616&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=date+time+oracle+storage+bytes) and the [first link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/storage-requirements.html) gives all the answers you need. Not really sure how you couldn't find it.

Comment: @DavidG Your "first link" is **NOT** the official **Oracle Documentation**, it is **MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual**. This happens with many folks. However, I must say that it is not a difficult task to find the answer with a google search.

Comment: @Mirek See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26652945/3989608

Comment: @LalitKumarB you missed there 8 byte `Type 13` Oracle runtime DATE

Comment: @agent5566 No, not at all. I haven't missed anything. I have contributed a lot to improvise the Oracle documentation on DATEs and literals. Do not confuse with **fractional seconds or a time zone**. The size is fixed at **7 bytes** with elements `YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND`. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330

Comment: @LalitKumarB Good spot! Though my point still stands, this information is simple fo look up!

Comment: @agent5566, Appreciate your involvement here. +1 and good going mate!

Comment: @LalitKumarB fixed **7 bytes** for storage data files, but date exressions in runtime is **8 byte**. http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/date_representation.htm. But as DavidG have said, it pretty easy to google ;)

Comment: Firstly, I got confused with the comments from DavidG and agent5566. David ,the incorrect link was for you, rest regarding the date storage is for @agent5566.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are dates stored in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/how-are-dates-stored-in-oracle)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DUMP` function to retrive information about expression value, like this `SELECT DUMP(SYSDATE,10) FROM dual`
and it says `Typ=13 Len=8: 223,7,4,23,14,17,41,0`, so **8 bytes**.
From oracle docs
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635

> DUMP returns a VARCHAR2 value containing the datatype code, length in
>   bytes, and internal representation of expr. The returned result is
>   always in the database character set.

Aslo, there are **two different** raw forms for DATEs in Oracle:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2257401

1. Type 12 (7 bytes) is used for DATE columns
2. Type 13 (8 bytes)
   is used for other DATE expressions, including DATE literals and results for date arithmetic and functions.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a date time format is fixed at 7 bytes, see [Oracle's documentation](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals.php#date) or alternatively run this:

```
select vsize(sysdate) from dual
```

or this:

```
create table test (dt date);

select data_length from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'ZTEST';
```